# How to do a "SELECT DISTINCT" with two "INNER JOIN"?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, inner-join

What I'm trying to do is to GetAPersonByID by doing some inner joins from different tables.

**TABLE PEOPLE**

| IDPerson | Name | LastName | E-mail | fk_ID_Skin |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Example | Explanation | help@please.com | 1 |
| 2 | Example2 | Explanation | ineed@somebody.com | 2 |

**TABLE SKINS**

| IDSkin | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Normal |
| 2 | Weird |

**TABLE PRODUCTS**

| IDProduct | Name | fk_skin_type | Photo |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Oil | 1 | PhotoOil |
| 2 | Water | 2 | PhotoWater |
| 3 | Cream | 2 | PhotoCream |

I need to know which products the CUSTOMER should use according to their SKIN TYPE
But... When I tried to do the InnerJoins (My apologies for the Spanish text in the database):

```
SELECT
  people.IDPerson AS 'Id_person',
  people.name AS 'Name',
  people.lastname AS 'Lastname',
  people.email AS 'E-mail',
  skins.name AS 'Skin',
  products.name AS 'Product',
  products.photo AS 'Photo'
FROM
  ((people
      INNER JOIN skins
        ON people.fk_ID_skin = skins.IDSkin)
    INNER JOIN products
      ON people.fk_ID_skin = products.fk_skin_type)
WHERE IDPerson = c_id;
```

[image: InnerJoinResult]

How can I show 'X Person' without repeating the data?
I'm using MySQL Workbench

Comment: Post your expected result and MySQL Workbench is a tool.. the difference in functionality depends on MySQL version instead; hence, to get the correct version, you can run `SELECT @@version` on your MySQL Workbench then [post the result into your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67223515/edit)

Comment: *How can I show 'X Person' without repeating the data?* On the screenshot two different `Producto` matches the same 'X Person'. Imagine that you save only one row - what value for `Producto` must be stored and what one must be lost, and why? PS. your screenshot does not match your SQL code, the columns names differs...

Answer (score 0):

> How can I show 'X Person' without repeating the data?

It sounds like you are saying you want to see only 1 row per person?  Assuming that's the case then I think what you are looking to do is GROUP BY IDPerson.  Then you could use the GROUP_CONCAT function in your SELECT statement to generate a comma separated list of the values Foto, Producto, etc.